# Android - Button del string bug

Tags: java, android, string, button

I have a button that deletes one character from the string. I have a problem, because when the string is empty and the button pressed my app crashes. How could I solve it? I think I should write an "if" that checks the string whether is empty or not, but I don't know how to make it.
Thanks in advance.

```
    case R.id.buttondel:

          String text = textview.getText().toString();
          textview.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
          break;
```

Comment: You have to test if the string length is > 0 before trying to delete a char. If it is, then delete. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: But this is I don't know how to do. Code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be getting IndexOutOfBoundsException. Just add one check:

```
case R.id.buttondel:

      String text = textview.getText().toString();
      if(text.length()>0)textview.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
      break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `String` before setting to `TextView` as below...

```
case R.id.buttondel:

    String text = textview.getText().toString();

    if (text != null && !text.equals("")) {

         textview.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
    }
    break;
```

You can also use `isEmpty()` method of `TextUtils` class to check that `String` doesn't contain empty value as below...

```
case R.id.buttondel:

    String text = textview.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {

         textview.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
    }
    break;
```